# PHP DOMDocument: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::save()

Tags: php, simplexml, domdocument

I'm trying to indent my XML file, but I can't because of this error.
Why is this problem appear?

[image: The problem]

This is my code:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = 'xmlfile.xml';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr, null, true);

$lastID = (int)$sxe->xpath("//tip[last()]/tipID")[0] + 1;

$tip = $sxe->addChild('tip');
$tip->addChild('tipID', $lastID);
$tip->addChild('tiptitle', 'Title:');   
$sxe->asXML($xmlstr);

$xmlDom = dom_import_simplexml($sxe);
$xmlDom->formatOutput = true;
$xmlDom->save($xmlstr);

?>
```

I've done a lot of research and I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: @splash58 Didn't solve it unfortunately. The error keeps the same, but with the saveXML instead of save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`dom_import_simplexml` function](http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml) returns an instance of [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), which has no `save` method. What you need instead is a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), which *does* have a `save` method.

Luckily, it's really easy to get from one to the other, because a `DOMElement` is a type of `DOMNode`, and so has an [`ownerDocument` property](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php). Note that the `formatOutput` attribute is also part of the `DOMDocument`, so what you need is this:

```
$xmlDom = dom_import_simplexml($sxe)->ownerDocument;
$xmlDom->formatOutput = true;
$xmlDom->save($xmlstr);
```

Answer (score 1):

DOMElement has not method to save xml, but DOMDocument does. Make DOMDocument before:

```
$xmlDom = dom_import_simplexml($sxe);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom_sxe = $dom->importNode($xmlDom, true);
$dom_sxe = $dom->appendChild($xmlDom);
$Dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```